# How rigorously can we apply the data supplied by this nonstandard attack on Kuratowski's closure-complement problem?

Tags: lo.logic, gn.general-topology, computer-science, intuition, formal-proof

Suppose a student assigned an advanced version of Kuratowski’s closure-complement problem to solve—one that leaves out the standard hint about the finite upper bound of $14$—decides to look for the upper bound by writing a computer program.  The program confirms (as [Anusiak and Shum - Remarks on finite topological spaces](https://doi.org/10.4064/cm-23-2-217-223) proved in 1971) that for $n=1$ to $7$, the largest family generated by one set in a topological space of cardinality $n$ has cardinality $2n.$ When the student discovers that instead of going up like before, the largest family still has the same cardinality when going from space cardinality $7$ to space cardinality $8$, they jubilantly exclaim: “Aha – it has to be 14!”

To what rigorous extent is the jubilation justified?  Is this merely a “good sign” the least upper bound is $14$ or is there some theory that rigorously guarantees that once the cardinality of the largest family fails to strictly increase going from space size $n$ to space size $n+1$, not only will it never go higher by continuing to increase the cardinality in finite spaces, it will in fact never be higher in any topological space at all?  What are the key properties (if any) of this specific question that would allow us to draw such a sweeping conclusion?  The non-increase going from $7$ to $8$ definitely *feels like* more than just a good sign to my intuition, but feelings only go so far in math.

Edit added 11 Oct 2022:

Perhaps the question is better asked using an example that only involves a finite number of possibilities from the start.  In 2007, [McCluskey, McIntyre, and Watson - The Propositional Theory of Closure](https://doi.org/10.1080/10586458.2007.10129017) proved that in a topological space, the number of different collections of inclusions that can hold among the (up to) seven distinct sets a subset $A$ generates under closure and interior is $49$.  (This result was also found independently by [Staiger and Wagner - There are Forty Nine Kuratowski Lattices](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/355773040_There_are_Forty_Nine_Kuratowski_Lattices) in 2010.)  I don't happen to know what the smallest $n$ is such that each of the $49$ collections can be found in some space of cardinality $n,$ but whatever it is, when it is discovered that no further collections are found when every subset in every space of cardinality $n+1$ is checked, then we can rest assured that our collection of $49$ is complete.

But why?  Is there some sense in which it is true that cardinality $n+2$ cannot produce any new collection of inclusions *because $n+1$ wasn't able to?* It seems intuitively obvious that this is so, but a logical explanation would be better.

Edit added 13 Oct 2022:

A little while ago I cross-posted my question more mathematically over in MSE: [does this counting property have a name?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4551938/does-this-counting-property-have-a-name)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139849/discussion-on-question-by-mathematrucker-how-rigorously-can-we-apply-the-data-su).